# Prolog recursion and building output from recursive calls

Tags: algorithm, recursion, prolog

I am learning Prolog via http://www.learnprolognow.org and I am having some trouble understanding how to recursively build up a variable with results from another recursive call, as per Practical Session 3.4, question 3.  The initial problem is a straight-forward recursive call to determine if a route is feasible.  But the follow-on problem asks you to show the actual path to get to the end of the route.

We are given the following knowledge base of travel information:

```
byCar(auckland,hamilton). 
byCar(hamilton,raglan). 
byCar(valmont,saarbruecken). 
byCar(valmont,metz).
byTrain(metz,frankfurt). 
byTrain(saarbruecken,frankfurt). 
byTrain(metz,paris). 
byTrain(saarbruecken,paris).
byPlane(frankfurt,bangkok). 
byPlane(frankfurt,singapore). 
byPlane(paris,losAngeles). 
byPlane(bangkok,auckland). 
byPlane(singapore,auckland). 
byPlane(losAngeles,auckland).
```

> Write a predicate travel/2 which determines whether it is possible to
>   travel from one place to another by chaining together car, train, and
>   plane journeys. For example, your program should answer yes to the
>   query travel(valmont,raglan).

I solved this problem with the following code:

```
travel(From,To) :-
 byCar(From,To).

travel(From,To) :-
 byTrain(From,To).

travel(From,To) :-
 byPlane(From,To).

travel(From,To) :-
  byCar(From,NewTo),
  travel(NewTo,To).

travel(From,To) :-
  byTrain(From,NewTo),
  travel(NewTo,To).

travel(From,To) :-
  byPlane(From,NewTo),
  travel(NewTo,To).
```

The follow-on problem is:

> So, by using travel/2 to query the above database, you can find out
>   that it is possible to go from Valmont to Raglan. If you are planning
>   such a voyage, that’s already something useful to know, but you would
>   probably prefer to have the precise route from Valmont to Raglan.
>   Write a predicate travel/3 which tells you which route to take when
>   travelling from one place to another. For example, the program should
>   respond

```
X  =  go(valmont,metz,go(metz,paris,go(paris,losAngeles)))
```

> to the query travel(valmont,losAngeles,X)

I have been struggling to populate X with a series of go(From,To) that show the successive steps of the journey.  It looks like a recursive problem but I do not know how one should go about tackling it.  This technique seems fundamental to Prolog programming, and I am quite interested in the thinking process to solve this problem and I look forward to any insight you can provide.

Comment: A user asked the same question in another post that I was not able to find on my initial search (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231815/recursion-in-prolog-finding-path-between-cities?rq=1).  I'll update my question if I am able to figure out my problem based on the response they received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a go at this. I made one change to your first solution, just to remove some redundancy. I used the predicate `connected/2` to generalize the relationship common to all connections appearing in the `by_car/2`, `by_train/2`, and `by_plane/2` facts:

```
connected(From, To) :- by_car(From, To).
connected(From, To) :- by_train(From, To).
connected(From, To) :- by_plane(From, To).
```

Then I defined `travel/2` as a recursive relationship over `connected/2`:

```
travel(From, To) :-
    connected(From, To).
travel(From, To) :-
    connected(From, Through),
    travel(Through, To).
```

Turning to `travel/3`, notice that the final connection in the nested `go...` terms is a structure `go/2`, but the rest are `go/3`s. So we need to populate `X` with a series of nested `go/3` structures that terminate in a `go/2`.  This last is our base condition. Then it is simply a matter of repeating the second clause of `travel/2`, but including a `go/3` in the third argument that will capture the values instantiated to `From` and `Through` on each iteration:

```
travel(From, To, go(From, To)) :-
    connected(From, To).
travel(From, To, go(From, Through, Route)) :-
    connected(From, Through),
    travel(Through, To, Route).
```

Comment: Great answer, you have clearly outlined a solution for this problem as well as added some useful tips for making the solution more efficient (e.g. adding the connection predicate).  

I am trying to wrap my head around your travel/3 with go(From, Through, Route), particularly how Route gets populated.  I understand how connected(From, Through) works, but I do not know how Route gets populated or how the base condition of travel/3 will finally get executed.  Any hints or tips are appreciated!